# React native implementing stack navigation error

Tags: react-native, expo, stack-navigator

I want to develop a customize app for my web based system to run with android and IOS. I am very beginner in using react native/expo for my project. I want to create a login page and dashboard for redirecting after login. Now i am having trouble in implementing the stack navigator since i was only following a youtube tutorial.

Here is my App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Login from './modules/Login.js';


export default createStackNavigator({
    login: Login,
})
```

Now Here is where i want to navigate first my Login.js where it is located at modules/login.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';

class Login extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.header}>
                      <Text style={styles.bigBlue}>Payroll App</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.inner}>
                    <View style={styles.inner_title}>
                        <Text style={styles.smallBlue}>Login here</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.inner_logdetails}>
                        <Text>Email</Text>
                        <TextInput style={styles.textLogin} placeholder='Email'

                        />
                        <Text>Password</Text>
                        <TextInput style={styles.textLogin} placeholder='Password'

                        />
                        <Button style={styles.btnLogin} title='Login'/>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.inner_footer}>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.footer}>
                </View>
            </View>
          );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

//Views
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  header: {
      padding: 5,
      flex: 2,
      backgroundColor: '#686868',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  inner: {
        flex: 7,
        backgroundColor: '#828181',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        padding: 20,
  },
  inner_title: {
        flex: 1,
  },
  inner_logdetails: {
        padding: 5,
        flex: 1,
  },
  inner_footer: {
        flex: 4,
  },
  footer: {
        backgroundColor: '#686868',
        flex: 1,
  },

//Text
  bigBlue: {
      marginTop: 30,
      color: 'powderblue',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      fontSize: 30,
  },
  smallBlue: {
        marginTop: 30,
        color: 'powderblue',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 24,
  },

//Button
  btnLogin: {
        marginTop: 10,
  },

//TextInput
      textLogin: {
            borderColor: 'white',
      }
});

export default Login
```

I am having an error in cmd if i tried to run my code:

Invariant Violation: The navigation prop is missing for this navigator. In react
-navigation 3 you must set up your app container directly. More info: https://re
actnavigation.org/docs/en/app-containers.html
- node_modules@react-navigation\core\lib\module\navigators\createNavigator.js:1
:1637 in getDerivedStateFromProps
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:68
96:46 in applyDerivedStateFromProps
- ... 20 more stack frames from framework internals

Warning: %s: Error boundaries should implement getDerivedStateFromError(). In th
at method, return a state update to display an error message or fallback UI., Ro
otErrorBoundary
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\YellowBox\YellowBox.js:59:8 in error
- node_modules\expo\build\environment\muteWarnings.fx.js:26:24 in error
- ... 28 more stack frames from framework internals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> import {   createStackNavigator,   createAppContainer } from
>   'react-navigation';
>   const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({...});
>
> const App = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

Refer to this link 
[React Navigation 3.0](https://reactnavigation.org/blog/2018/11/17/react-navigation-3.0.html)

Please note the tutorial you followed might have used react navigation 2.0 but it was a breaking change in react navigation 3.0. Follow the above link and it will solve the error.

It just means that you have to wrap your main exported component in `createAppContainer`

Comment: You're most welcome. If it was useful, support the answer giving an upvote :)